# How to get all tree-like refutations of a formula

Tags: satisfiability

I need to extract all tree-like refutations of this formula

$$(a+b)(a+ b')(a'+c)(a'+c')\,.$$

I get understand this one

[image]

but how do I get the other ones?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a tree-like refutation of a formula?

Comment: Is this about Krom's resolution algorithm? Alternatively, you can think about the strongly-connected-component approach to 2-SAT and see whether you can reconstruct resolution trees for "bad" variables. You may also want to think about how many trees there may be, and maybe a recursion for how they decompose. If the question is solely about this one formula, back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest there should be something like less than 36 tress in total, so you can go through them one by one.